# Suppress Cursor Changes in Mac Catalyst App

Tags: macos, ipad, cursor, mac-catalyst

Is it possible to suppress the cursor changes in Mac Catalyst? Here is an example of what I'm talking about. This app was originally written for iPad but support for Mac was added. Here a modal view controller is shown. I've add a red dot to close the view controller using a hover gesture recognizer to display the X like in the Mac apps since tapping outside the view controller as works in iPad doesn't work in Catalyst. The problem is, the cursor changes at the edge of the view. This view is not resizable, so there is no point in changing the cursor. I'd rather it be just the default arrow. I have another view where I change the cursor using a hover gesture recognizer, and that works fine. Maybe I could try the same approach here, but where would install the gesture recognizer?

[image]

I've tried adding a hover gesture recognizer to the view controller's view and also to that view's window. Neither works. I'm guessing there's some simple method I can use that I don't know about.

Edited: this time I tried clicking and dragging when the cursor changed to the double arrow. This allowed me to drag some view (the transition view maybe?) apparently just one point, at which point when the cursor changes, it's just a down arrow. It looks like I can drag whatever view that is one point in any direction and back. Notice the inside of the view also changes.

[image: clicking and dragging at edge]

Here is what the view hierachy looks like.
[image: view hierarchy]

Comment: Maybe it's not possible, unless, perhaps if I use `prefersPointerLocked`, but then there is no cursor at all. I'd have to roll my own. For now, I'm solving this by moving the red button father away from the edge. It now is positioned like the one Catalyst installs for the main window.

Answer (score 0):

##### Update:

The author provided additional information that clarified the question. The problem is the cursor changes from arrow to resize at the edges of a modally-presented-view even though the view is not really resizable. In my opinion this is a bug as there is no public api as of this writing where the developer can indicate whether this modally-presented-view is resizable or not.

##### Original Answer:

There may be a clever trick to achieve what you are asking in UIKitForMac that I am not aware of. It appears to me is that you want to control the mouse tracking area - which is managed by [NSTrackingArea](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstrackingarea) api. This API is only available for macOS at the time of this writing and is only designed to work with NSView - not UIView.

Another possibility is that we do know that cursor movements do register as hover events. You can create a [UIHoverGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uihovergesturerecognizer/) and attach it to your UIView of interest. When hover is detected gesture action will be called - such as this:

```
    @objc
    func hovering(_ recognizer: UIHoverGestureRecognizer) {
        switch recognizer.state {
        case .began, .changed:
            //mouse is hovering
            //now check the location of the hover 
            let hoverPoint = recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)
            if hoverPoint == CGPoint.zero {
              //do something with cursor, say hide it
              NSCursor.hide()
            } else {
              //do something else with cursor, say show it
              NSCursor.unhide()
            }
        case .ended:
            //mouse is no longer hovering on the UIView
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I explored that. " I have another view where I change the cursor using a hover gesture recognizer, and that works fine. Maybe I could try the same approach here, but where would install the gesture recognizer?" Maybe I'll try again, but as I recall, everything I tried was fruitless.

Comment: Is that a window’s edge or modally presented view’s edge when the cursor changes shape? If that is a window's edge, there might be a way. Waiting to hear from you.

Comment: It is a modally (formsheet) presented view.

Comment: Ok. It appears that you are asking "can I prevent the cursor from changing at the edges of my modally-presented-view when it is not resizable?" If I understood your question correctly, I will update my answer to reflect this. It appears that this is a bug from Apple.

Comment: I edited the question to show what happens when the edges are dragged. It's a different view this time, but it is presented the same way and shows the same issue. I suspect that the reason using a hover event recognizer doesn't work is because it really needs to be added to a view added by Apple, like the transition view. Maybe the only way to resolve this is by creating my own transition manager.

Comment: Interestingly, depending on which edge is dragged, the view is either shifted in the same direction as the drag or in the opposite direction. How odd.

Comment: I noticed the same effect as well. It appears that content is moving like 1-2 pixels - all the more reason that it appears to be a bug on Apple's side.